# c adding auto suggestions to my editor

Tags: c++, c

I am writing my own c/c++ editor, and now that I am done with everything I want to add auto suggestions while I am writing, to do that I need to parse the header that are included in my current file and organize them into a JSON structure , I am looking for the design that gives me the best performance, but i barely have experience in that area, so here is how I started it, suppose I had this simple c program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/scoket.h>
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I have a class called document and it has 3 arrays :

1. holds all the names of each header included, its content changes
   based on my inculde statements, so for the above document its contents are

   "stdio"
      "stdlib"
      "scoket"
2. holds all the suggestions that are got from the JSON files that are listed in the first array and organizes them , and recognizes the types of function parameters, and a comment per suggestion etc..
3. holds the matching suggestions, and it keeps changing based on whats
   being typed.

as I said I don't have experience and I didn't read about how they do it but apart from the JSON part is that how they add auto suggestion to an IDE?

also I would appreciate some hints that could help me improve this design or even scrap it.

ps: if anyone wonders why JSON its because i am going to make an online version of it!

Comment: `#include<sys/scoket.h>`? :)

Comment: @BЈовић just an example! this question has nothing to do with sockets http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html

Comment: Maybe take a look at [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. A) Write a conforming C parser able to navigate the maze of CPP (not C++, CPP) preprocessor operators.

OR

Step 1. B) Harness an existing, conforming C compiler to do the parsing for you, possibly by means of:

- calling `cpp -E` and then parsing its C-language output that has had the CPP operators "white-washed" out of it
- invoking `gccxml` and parsing its XML output http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html
- hooking directly into `clang` or `gcc` using various hooks to process their internal parse trees (This is what e.g. XCode does for its realtime processing, I believe) — http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals/Print_version http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html

Step 2. Determine what the current context of the line at the point (cursor position) in your editor is; e.g.

- is the user expecting to enter a general term?
- are they dereferencing a pointer to a structure or object, or using the `.` operator against one, and need a member (method, field) name?
- are they at the start of a new statement and may be entering a type name for a variable or function?
- are they invoking a function with a known parameter list, and you know that they are providing the (nth) parameter, ergo that parameter must be of type (T), then they must be entering a literal value or expression of type (T)

This part you might use some syntax hints without invoking a full compiler, and may be a bit hit-or-miss.

Step 3. Find all definitions that are in scope at the point and fulfill the type requirements of what the user might be expecting to enter there. This list might include values from header files, from within the current file, or from within local scopes within a function/method as well.

Step 4. As the user begins typing, narrow the selection to only those that meet the type determined in 2, which begin with the letter(s) already entered in the word (although you might want to fold case, i.e. make it case-insensitive, and possibly ignore `_` underscores as they're inconsistently used between different libraries and the like)

---

Step 1. C) Build up a hashtable (possibly case-folding and `_`-eliding) of all “words seen” in the collection of files in the project, and simply winnow that list to those words beginning with the letters typed so far, regardless of type.

Believe it or not, for my relatively rare forays into `C` code, I mostly don't bother enabling the full stack of (1B-4) above in Emacs, I just use the `dabbrev-expand` option (`M-/`) which works like (1C) here, and more-often-than-not am happy with the results. If you're writing an editor specifically for just handling C and C++ code, though, you'd probably want to try something a bit more like (1B-4), I'd expect.